# Getting a cherrypy Hello World running on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cherrypy

I am trying to do a simple proof of concept on a new EC2 instance in which I run the "Hello World" tutorial code from the CherryPy distribution.

CherryPy launches successfully, and a wget run directly on the EC2 instance successfully retrieves the Hello World page.  However, trying to access the same page from my own machine results in a "could not connect" error.

CherryPy is running on port 8080, and my EC2 instance is set up with a security group that ought to be allowing traffic from anywhere to connect to port 8080.

Here is my CherryPy tutorial.conf:

```
[global]
server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"
server.socket_port = 8080
server.thread_pool = 10
```

I have tried connecting to the web server using both the public DNS listed in the AWS management console, as well as by setting up an elastic IP; neither allows a successful connection.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please share your code on how you acheived doing this. Im still not able to access it. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [socket_host](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.html#cherrypy._cpserver.Server.socket_host) to the server ip or '0.0.0.0' for external access.

Comment: Thank you. 
I spent hours looking for a solution but found nothing that worked. 
Thanks a lot!